# Are there any websites dedicated to the distribution of Visual Studio Macros?

Tags: visual-studio, macros, web

Preferably a site that has macros searchable by Visual Studio version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the web's top Visual Studio project site is http://www.codeproject.com. You'll find lots of macros there.

Specifically, check http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/

I think there is no specific search for Studio versions, but each macro in there carry its own compatibility specification.